# How to render events for selected user from select list on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to render only events assigned for a specific user. At start fullcalendar render events for logged user (it works). Further, I am using selectlist to send choosen userid to controller. In response I get json with all events of selected user.

I've tried to use 'eventSources', but when I try to call function with selected events, I can't use 'callback' cause of error in console: "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function at Object.success"

I do the following:

fullcalendar init

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 700,
        header: {
            left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
            right: 'none'
        },
        eventRender(event, $el) {
            $el.qtip({
                content: {
                    title: event.title,
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'unfocus'
                },
                show: {
                    solo: true
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'top left',
                    at: 'bottom left',
                    viewport: $('#calendar-wrapper'),
                    adjust: {
                        method: 'shift'
                    }
                }
            });
        },
       eventSources: [
          getEvents,
          getAnotherUserEvents
        ],

    });
```

Function with events of logged user:

```
function getEvents(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    const apiUrl = "https://localhost:44308/event/";
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl + '/getevents',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (doc) {
            var events = [];
            if (doc != undefined && doc.length > 0) {
                doc.forEach(function (entry) {
                    entry.destinationTimeViewModel.forEach(function (dt) {
                        events.push({
                            title: dt.subject,
                            description: dt.description,
                            start: dt.startedAt,
                            end: dt.endedAt
                        });
                    });
                    events.push({
                        title: entry.subject,
                        description: entry.description,
                        start: entry.startedAt,
                        end: entry.endedAt,
                        color: entry.color,
                        user: entry.users,
                        id: entry.id
                    });
                });
            }
            callback(events);

        },
    });
};
```

Function with events of selected user (data contains selected user Id)

```
function getAnotherUserEvents(start, end, timezone, callback, data) {
    const apiUrl = "https://localhost:44308/event/";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + '/GetAnotherUserEvents',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "Id": data.id,
        },
        success: function (doc) {
            var events = [];
            if (doc != undefined && doc.length > 0) {
                doc.forEach(function (entry) {
                    entry.destinationTimeViewModel.forEach(function (dt) {
                        events.push({
                            title: dt.subject,
                            description: dt.description,
                            start: dt.startedAt,
                            end: dt.endedAt
                        });
                    });
                    events.push({
                        title: entry.subject,
                        description: entry.description,
                        start: entry.startedAt,
                        end: entry.endedAt,
                    });
                });
            }
            callback(events);
        },
    })
}
```

Do you have any ideas how can I display only events of selected user?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error exactly? is it the `callback(events)` from `getEvents()` or the same line from `getAnotherUserEvents()`?

Comment: P.S. I don't know where you think that `data` variable is coming from in `getAnotherUserEvents(start, end, timezone, callback, data)`? how is fullCalendar going to know to provide that extra parameter when it executes you callback? It cannot and will not know that. Whatever is supposed to be in `data`, you need to fetch it another way. I guess it intended to come from the value in your select list?? If so then you can simply get the value from the select list directly e.g. `$("#myselectlist").val()`